# compare two large hexadecimal number in Java

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I wanted to compare two hexadecimal strings in Java.
The string's are usually very large in length, Example: 1048576,16777216.
So I converted the Strings to Big Integer and compared it.

Few Strings i could use Big Integer and could compare but if something very large so the system crashes and not able to proceed further.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Code for converting String to Big Integer,
BigInteger mFirst = new BigInteger(pFirst, 16)

Comment: This strings do not seem to be very large "1048576" = 7 chars, or do you mean that there are 1048576 chars in the string?

Comment: There's a BigDecimal class with more memory allocated to store bigger numbers.

Comment: In data mining concept, we generally normalize the data by dividing the numbers with 1000000 or 10000000 or 100 and then compare them.

Comment: 1048576,16777216 are the length of the strings. Thank you all the replies. I will try using BigDecimal and also dividing the numbers and comparing and will let you know the results.

Comment: I tried using BigDecimal and it works....yahoooo... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the numbers just as they are in string representation. Just walk through the both Strings right-to-left and compare each hex-digit.